# Как изменить тип переменной внутри вариативного шаблона?

Tags: c++, c++11

Как изменить тип переменой внутри данного шаблона: `template <typename... Args>`?
Например если передали `string "str"` то поменять на `jstring "str"` (Функция конвертора написана)

Стоит задача написать удобную обертку для вызова JNI из C++.
Вызов самой функции:

```
CallJni("com/NameCompany/NameProject/NameClass", "NameFunction", "Str for JNI", 0.f, 1.f, 2.f);
```

Хедер самой функции:

```
template <typename... Args>
static void CallJni(const char* ClassName, const char* FunctionName, Args... args)
```

Как можно параметры `args...` переконвертировать в самой функции `CallJni` в зависимости от их типа `(string, int, float...)` и передать дальше все тем же вариативным шаблоном? Были идеи через указатель и static_cast, но только вообще без понятие как это реализовать.

Палки в колеса вставляет то что собирается это дело на:

```
NDK toolchain: r14b, GccVersion: 4.9, ClangVersion: 3.8.275480
```

Поддержка c++11 не полная у данного NDK

Всю остальную обертку я написал, и если `"Str for JNI"` предварительно переконвертировать в jstring `GetJavaString("Str for JNI")`, то функция отлично работает

Comment: я бы завёл пустой шаблонный класс и добавил специализацию для string...

Comment: Вам нужно какое-то однозначное соответствие м/у типами? string -> jstring, int -> kint, float -> lfloat ... etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Легко: делаете перегруженную функцию, преобразующую аргументы в нужные типы:

```
template <typename T>
const T &convertArg(const T &value) {return value;}

jstring ConvertArg(const char *str) {return /*...*/;}
```

А потом в теле `CallJni` меняете `args...` на `ConvertArg(args)...`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример на коленке:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class JStr {
public:
    std::string str;
    JStr(std::string str): str(str) {}
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const JStr& self) {
            return stream << "JStr(" << self.str << ")";
        }
};

template <class T> auto convert(T a) {return a;}
template <> auto convert(string a) {return JStr(a);}

template <typename... TArgs>
static void foo(TArgs... args) {
    int dummy[sizeof...(TArgs)] = { (std::cout << convert(args) << ", ", 0)... };
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a{1};
    string b{"Hello"};

    foo(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```